# When do MessageBoxes not act modally?

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

I have always thought MessageBoxes were sort of like break points -- they stopped a program from executing until the user clicked "OK." However, I just discovered that's inaccurate and I'm trying to figure out when MessageBoxes will and won't stop execution.

Searching SO (successfully) for the solution to a problem I discovered this pseudocode:

```
if (somethingHappened())
{
   timer1.Enabled = false; 
   MessageBox.Show("something happened");              
}
else continue with other stuff ...
```

behaves differently from this:

```
if (somethingHappened())
{
   MessageBox.Show("something happened"); 
   timer1.Enabled = false;              
}
else continue with other stuff ...
```

In the first case, the timer stops and the message box is displayed. In the second case, the message box is displayed but the timer *isn't* stopped. The program just goes on to the other stuff. Apparently, the MessageBox must be clicked before the timer will stop, but my program just kept going. (The event handler was called again, another MessageBox appeared, and it was stuck in an infinite loop.)

So, under what conditions will a MessageBox **not** be truly modal, failing to stop execution of a program until the user responds?

Comment: _In the second case, the message box is displayed but the timer isn't stopped. The program just goes on to the other stuff._ I don't think so. The timer keeps Ticking, yes, but the lines after the curly brace will not be executed.

Comment: The current thread is halted by means of a MessageBox, other threads will simply continue functioning. Apparently 'the event handler' to which you're referring operates on a different thread than the thread that creates the actual messagebox. Not necessarily a thread you manually created but a thread nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message box is modal. But in order to service its GUI it runs what is known as a modal message loop. That message loop pulls dispatches synchronous messages, and also processes asynchronous messages. Like `WM_TIMER`. And that latter fact is what means that your timer continues firing.

You call `MessageBox.Show` and that really does not return until the dialog is closed. But inside `MessageBox.Show` is a loop that processes messages. And part of that message processing involves calling your timer event. It's quite possible for this to result in a stack overflow due to non-terminating recursion. And that's precisely what happened to you.

The key point to take away from this is that `MessageBox.Show` dispatches timer events (amongst others), which can lead to re-entrancy.

Comment: The only answer that correctly mentions the modal message loop. Critical for the OP to understand the root of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

A `MessageBox` never stops execution of *the program*.  It just stops execution of that sequence of code which invokes it.  So in this case:

```
timer1.Enabled = false; 
MessageBox.Show("something happened");
```

The timer stopped because you set `Enabled` to `false`.  But in this case:

```
MessageBox.Show("something happened"); 
timer1.Enabled = false;
```

The timer hasn't stopped because until you get past the `MessageBox` dialog you *haven't* set `Enabled` to `false`.  Imperative code statements execute in the order in which they're written.  The second line won't execute until the first line has completed.

This has no bearing on other threads within the application.  Just the one which invoked the `MessageBox`.

Comment: Imo, this (and all other anwers so far) does not agree with the claim the the program did 'go on to the other stuff' which doesn't seem to be in another thread..I doubt the claim.

Comment: @TaW It's re-entrancy due to the modal message loop, as per my answer

Comment: @TaW: Perhaps "another thread" isn't entirely accurate.  I'm not *that* familiar with the inner workings.  (Though David Heffernan's answer seems much more descriptive of those workings.)  But the point is that the application continues to process.  Modal dialogs don't stop the application, the line that invokes them simply doesn't return until they're dismissed.  Other things which don't wait for that line (such as a `Timer` tick) are unaffected.

Comment: It all happens on the thread that called `MessageBox.Show`. You can observe this with a single threaded program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `MessageBox.Show()` is a modal window, execution of the thread that executed the message box is effectively blocked from continuing until the window is closed.  So your `timer1.enabled` code is only executed after closing, of course other threads are unaffected by this and will continue to execute, even the code executed on behalf of the timer object.

There is no Non-Modal `MessageBox.Show()` method, you would have to write your own messagebox form if you wanted non modal behavior.